# Autosizing Cells Not Working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios11

I am populating my UITableView from a web service. Here are all the constraints. Some of the items like Cheese Burgers has 10 lines of text which is not displayed.

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: You know the drill. Paste some codes :)

Comment: There is no code! In iOS 11 it is suppose to work by default.

Comment: Check my answer. Don't you wanna support iOS 9 and 10? I'm sure you have to, if so, the my answer might answer your question.

Comment: No I don't want to support iOS 9 or iOS 10 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable automatic resizing of your `UITableViewCell`, set the `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` of your `UITableView` in your controller's `viewDidLoad()` method, like so:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

And then if you would like or you need to implement the `heightForRow` `UITableViewDelegate` method, don't forget to pass again the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to whatever `row` or `section` that needs an auto resizing cell, like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let section = indexPath.section
    if let itemSection = ItemTableViewSections(rawValue: section) {
        switch itemSection {
        case .header: return 80.0
        case .photos: return 95.0
        case .note: return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        case .rejectOptions: return 50.0
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```

Lastly, don't forget to select an answer if an answer really answers your question just like in your last question :)

EDIT: I made a sample project that uses Storyboard and targeting merely iOS 11. All works fine. **Just don't forget to set your label's constraint** - top, bottom, leading, and trailing. These constraints will be required for autoresizing cell. Lastly, set the `UILabel`'s number of lines to 0.

[image]

Comment: This is the old way of doing things! In iOS 11 as I am showing in the screenshot it is expected to work by default but it does not.

Comment: I see, see my edit. Basically, nothing has changed in making your tableViewCell autoresizing. I can see that the `UITableView`'s rowHeight and estimatedRowHeight just became editable in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks! The constraints were the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

increase **Vertical Content Hugging Priority** by **1** of UILabel

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, try setting Content Compression Resistance Priority to 1000. That's how I fixed my problem.